# Filtering a DataTable and inserting the result into another datatable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I am working on a dataset with has several records in it and I have a method which accepts a datatable as an input parameter.

For example, I have a dataset named `dsDetails` and one of the table in it is `Charges` with the following data

```
Type Rate Name
B    14   bbb
A    10   ABC
C    12   ccc
```

I am passing the above datatable to my c# method as follows

```
Populate(dsDetails.Tables["Charges"]);
```

Everything looks fine, but now that I want to filter the above datatable by type and want to pass the datatable with records of `Type=A`

**May I know good way to do that to pass a filtered datatable?**

Comment: `Everything looks fins` Show the code which looks fine.

Comment: "Everything looks fins" - I'd say things look much more Broncs and Panthers, but at any rate why not read the Charges table into a new DataTable, filtering as you go, and then pass that new filtered table as the arg to Populate()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use a DataView object for that:

```
DataView dv = new DataView(dsDetails.Tables["Charges"]);
dv.RowFilter = "Type = 'A'";
Populate(dv.ToTable());
```